# Windows - Git keeps reverting remote origin URL

Tags: windows, git, github, ssh

I'm trying to use the following code to remove old branches:

`for k in $(git branch -r --merged | sed /\*/d); do 
  if [ -z "$(git log -1 --since='December 31, 2016' -s $k)" ]; then
    branch_name_with_no_origin=$(echo $k | sed -e "s/origin\///")
    echo delete branch: $branch_name_with_no_origin
    git push origin --delete $branch_name_with_no_origin
  fi
done`

I have SSH setup and working. However, a few loops in, this command will ALWAYS start asking me for my username and password, even though it works to begin with. If I then check my remote origin URL, it's been reverted to the `https` version. No matter how many times I change it to `git+ssh://git@github.com/username/repository.git`, it always changes back after a seemingly random number of branches have been removed.

Is this a bug? I can't think of why else it would happen.

Comment: Do you have more than one remote defined?  What does `git remote -v` show?

Comment: I'd even go farther and ask for a git config -l (mask credentials of course)  To me it sounds like maybe your git config is changing under you.  Is it possible you had a local git config